# Time series with External business events

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I've been trying to forecast some variables based on 3 years of past data at a monthly level where the seasonality is 12 months
I'm using the `stl( )` function to breakdown a time series object using:

```
fit <- stl(data.ts, t.window=12, s.window="periodic", robust=TRUE)
```

where 'data.ts' is a time series object and then forecasting for the next 12 months using:

```
f<- forecast(fit,method="naive",h=12)
```

This is under-forecasting for some months due to some external event which was not present in the historic data.
I wanted to know if there is any way to capture such events in my time series forecast

Comment: I read about the tsoutlier() package which detects the outliers and predicts the series after removing it's effects
What i want to do is the opposite, I want to include the effects of these outliers such as a step shift in a given month say February should bump up my forecast for all the months succeeding February

Answer (score 1):

You can try  auto.arima or arima function from forecast package.You can use a  df with external variables in the xreg parameter

Check this:
 https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1